# How can I increase AC for a Wilden Shaman|Runepriest?

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization

My son has a hybrid Wilden Shaman|Runepriest and his AC is awful. How can I get it higher?

He's taken no feats related to AC/defense and is level 4. Rebuilds are possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the **Hybrid Talent** feat with the **Runepriest Armor Proficiency** option.

This gives him scale armor (up from leather) and light shields.  This should get him up to a 21 ac or thereabouts.  A gain of +6 over his likely current AC for one feat can't be beat.

10 + scale armor (+7) + light shield (+1) + 4th level (+2) + magical armor (+1) = 21

If he is lacking magic armor, a 20 is still respectable.

Some typical 4th level opponents and their attacks:

- Orc Drudge (4th level minion @ +9)
- Orc Archer (4th level arty @ +11)
- Ghoul Flesh Seeker (4th level lurker @ +9)

By the "book" everything should have Level+5 to their AC attack and a 20-21 would be a very reasonable defense against that.

Comment: I'll just give a good story reason to upgrade his leather to scale. They're currently getting ready to do some favors for a dwarf artisan in a giant mushroom forest by dealing with sentient ants who craft gold bells so I'm sure there will be a good opportunity.

Comment: My wife's Runepriest just got the feat to wear plate armor and I think she likes it.  It makes him like a defender.  She also took the feat that takes off the speed penalty.